# Where is the nuget cache located for the LOCAL SYSTEM account?

Tags: nuget, teamcity, local-system-account

The nuget cache for a user account is normally located under
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache`.
But where is it to be found for the LOCAL SYSTEM account? This special user has no ordinary profile.

This combination is a quite common scenario for a build server, e.g. TeamCity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On a 32-bit machine it's located under
`%windir%\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache`.

On a 64-bit machine it's located under
`%windir%\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache`.